# Filling In Empty Dates With Previous Data in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

So I have the current file in Excel where I have dates and don't have dates for everything which can be seen.

[image]

I read this excel file into a pandas dataframe, rename the column and get the following:

[image]

My question is, how would I get it so every empty date in the dataframe is filled in with the last previous date encountered. All of the blanks between 04/03/2021 and 05/03/2021 gets replaced with 04/03/2021, so every row in my dataframe has a date associated with it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the data into a dataframe, you can fill missing values using [fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) with method='ffill' for forward fill

Answer (score 0):

Just using the inbuilt way in pandas of:

```
duplicate_df['StartDate'] = duplicate_df['StartDate'].fillna(method = 'ffill')
```

This replaces all the NaNs in the dataframe with the last row that had data in.